# Dynamic variable from user input

Tags: ruby, class, variables

I'm trying to get a user's input to create a new `User` object:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :age
  attr_accessor :email
end

puts "Name:"
input = gets.chomp.to_s
name = "#{input} = User.new"

puts "Age:"
age = gets.chomp.to_s

puts "Email:"
email = gets.chomp.to_s

name.name = "#{input}"
name.age = "#{age}"
name.email = "#{email}"

puts "Name: #{input.name}, Age: #{input.age}, E-mail: #{input.email}"
```

How can I call the newly created object so that I can input new attributes? Do I need to change the `name` part of

```
name.name = "#{input}"
name.age = "#{age}"
name.email = "#{email}"
```

to the user's input?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `input = gets.chomp.to_s` is a String, and a string does not have any `name`, `age` and `email` methods you should be creating a new `User` object and then fill it with the information the user gives you, you're code is not so far from the answer but there are a lot's of little mistakes, here is the following working code:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :age
  attr_accessor :email
end

user = User.new

puts "Name:"
user.name = gets.chomp.to_s

puts "Age:"
user.age = gets.chomp.to_s

puts "Email:"
user.email = gets.chomp.to_s

puts "Name: #{user.name}, Age: #{user.age}, E-mail: #{user.email}"
```

I hope it helps you.

By the way, what were you trying to achieve with this line: `name = "#{input} = User.new"` ? Because you're only creating a new string with the content "User.new" (as a string literal, it's not executed by Ruby in any way, you will never have a new object by surrounding its declaration with double (or single) quotes.